# convert python object to protocol buffer object

Tags: python, django, protocol-buffers

I have a django app up and running.
We have to support **serialisation via protobuf.** 
For achieving the same we want to do minimum changes to our codebase and hence what we are doing is keeping the code as is which creates a python object returns json.

We have created a .proto file with the same expected format and and compiled the same.
Now at the time of returning the response, i want to convert the **python object into protobuf object.**


**I am trying to do this via code:**

```
response = proto_object(**result)
```

This results in following error:

```
ValueError: Field name must be a string
```

Can somebody tell us what is wrong with above initialisation of protobuf and also the right way of achieving this.

I will share the .proto file if that is of any use.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this question is old, yet I found it via the search. For future searchers, I'll give an answer.

The problem can occur when you pass in a dict but your Protobuf message definition expects an object there. For instance take something like this:

```
message Inner {
  map<uint32, double> values = 1;
}

message Outer {
  repeated Inner inners = 1;
}
```

You might have something represented as Python primitives like this:

```py
outer = {"inners": [{1: 1.0}]}
```

Now if you try to convert that using `pb.Outer(**outer)`, when you will encounter this message. Implicitly it will try to create `Inner` instances from the dict `{1: 1.0}`, but *that* key (`1`) is not a string.

The solution is to write something like this:

```py
pb.Outer(inners=[pb.Inner(values=x) for x in outer["inners"]])
```